# CLLocationManager randomness & speed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

When using `CLLocationManager` I noticed that there seems to be a large margin of error for each of the `CLLocation` points generated by `didUpdateToLocation`. I'm using an array of these points in the order that they are generated to calculate the total distance moved by the user.

With the inaccuracy of these readings, I noticed that running the application on a completely stationary device could result in a large distance "moved" without any actual movement taking place.

This is the code I'm using to calculate the distance

```
- (double) sendTotalDistance
{
    if (locations.count < 2) return 0;
    double howFar = 0.0;
    for (int j=0; j<locations.count-1; j++)
    {
        howFar += [[locations objectAtIndex:j] distanceFromLocation:[locations objectAtIndex:j+1]];
    }
    return howFar;
}
```

**Question:** What is the best way to compensate for the random inaccuracy of these readings?

I was thinking about running a linear regression on the points, but of course this would assume that the user was moving in a line. I've been trying to brainstorm some way to include the accuracy of the reading in the calculation but all the ways I can think of make a lot of assumptions or introduce some other form of error.

**Update:** What I'm trying now is increasing the update rate and averaging some of the values. Problem is that this assumes the error is uniformly distributed.

**Update:** I've been logging the various locations reported by the program, and I noticed the `speed=-1.0` variable in the description. How accurate does this variable tend to be? If it's accurate enough it would seem possible to ignore measurements with a less than or close to 0 speed.

Comment: Have you tried checking the horizontalAccuracy of the reported CLLocation ? My understanding is that CLLocationManager reports updates as the location gets more and more accurate. Also you may find that it often reports the previous location when you start it. You can check the timestamp to filter these out.

Comment: The `horizontalAccuracy` value tends to be uniformly around ~65m. I'll check though, because I've been throwing out some updates.

Comment: How good is the GPS signal where you're testing?

Comment: @tc. I've been testing it in different areas, some better than others. The point is to write a flexible algorithm that can adapt to poor GPS accuracy.

Comment: The docs say "A negative value indicates an invalid speed" (I'm assuming you've requested the maximum accuracy/update rate). I suspect the problem is fundamentally hard — the movement you're seeing might be due to different satellites coming into view, which you can't really account for because the API doesn't give you that data (the GPS chipset probably doesn't expose it either). I've thought about combining accel/gyro data, but that also seems like a difficult problem.

Comment: I do have a step-tracking algorithm running at the same time. You're definitely right that this is a fundamentally difficult problem; I'm just trying to bring the error down to within a few percent with whatever compensation for randomness I can.